# Impersonation with visual studio development server

Tags: iis, impersonation, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to simulate impersonation with asp.net. If I use my application with IIS I don't have any problem and simulate the impersonation correctly, but if i use the VS development server I receive this message:

Impersonation of ... failed! [1326] Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the credentials of the current Windows user when trying to use impersonation with VS Development Server?

As far as I can remember only this user can be used, because the application is running as an executable.

Here is a solution of another user facing your problem:

"Actually, after setting the project to use IIS and creating a virtual directory, I can also now use the built in web server to debug it."

Maybe this helps.